# .NET Framework obstructing my project being pushed to github

Tags: git, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

I am trying to push a project to github for the first time but I keep getting a prompt from git-credential-manager-core.exe - This application could not be started with the message:

```
This application requires one of the following versions of the .NET Framework; 
.NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2 
Do you want to install this .NETFramework now?
```

I did download and install the latest framework which said it wasn't supported on this computer. Then I downloaded the 4.7.2 version but got the same error message.

Please help, this is frustrating me

Comment: Do you need the credential manager? You could try disabling it and using SSH keys to authenticate. Not a solution, but a workaround.

Comment: Well, I just clicked on No and it kinda worked for me by going ahead to let me login to github from cmd so I think that works for me for now but I really wish there could be a way to stop the pop up